# Split list of strings into column by spaces

Tags: python, arrays, list, split

I have a list of strings in python:

```
list =['Observed on Date 56370 at 850 F, -0.272 +/- 1.035', 
       'Observed on Date 56372 at 849 F, 0.051 +/- 0.945',
       'Observed on Date 56381 at 850 F, 0.101 +/- 0.353',]
```

I would like to split this into an array with columns delimited at each space in each string.

I'm not sure where to start with this, and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a little vague about the exact format wanted for the output, so here's a method that will produce a list of columns, each containing all the values in one of the space-delimited columns in the input:

```
from pprint import pprint

data = ['Observed on Date 56370 at 850 F, -0.272 +/- 1.035',
        'Observed on Date 56372 at 849 F, 0.051 +/- 0.945',
        'Observed on Date 56381 at 850 F, 0.101 +/- 0.353',]

columns = list(zip(*(row.split() for row in data)))
pprint(columns)
```

Results:

```
[('Observed', 'Observed', 'Observed'),
 ('on', 'on', 'on'),
 ('Date', 'Date', 'Date'),
 ('56370', '56372', '56381'),
 ('at', 'at', 'at'),
 ('850', '849', '850'),
 ('F,', 'F,', 'F,'),
 ('-0.272', '0.051', '0.101'),
 ('+/-', '+/-', '+/-'),
 ('1.035', '0.945', '0.353')]
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
split_list = [x.split() for x in initial_list]
```

Also, mind naming your variable list. You're shadowing the built-in **list** type in Python.